# How can I deploy my next js web application automatically from github to cpanel?

Tags: reactjs, github, next.js, cpanel

I want to deploy my next js web application by Cpanel automatically from GitHub.
So, when I push any new code to github it should be automatically deployed by cpanel to my hosting.
I need to know the process for-

1. Next js application
2. React js application

Kindly guide me through this.
thank you

Comment: have you checked Github Actions?

Comment: Check this URl

 https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583302-how-can-i-deploy-a-git-repository 

Kindly look at the "Auto Deployment" Option there.

Hope this helps you.